# Change the iOS double tap home button reachabity predefined function

Tags: ios, ui, iphone

I would like to set the double tap on the home button on the iPhone 6s as a click on the same home button.
Has anybody done this?

Comment: Even if possible, that would mean you would have to move the 'close app' function to another command.

Comment: That is just what I would like to do with the double tap. Close the current app as clicking.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible without jailbreaking. Apple does not provide any mechanism for changing the functionality of the double tap.

If the device is jailbroken, you can install [Activator 1.9.11 beta 2](http://rpetri.ch/cydia/activator/beta/) which has support for the ‘Double Press’ Touch ID event. This event can be mapped to ‘Home Button’, such that ‘touch fingerprint sensor twice’ will ‘simulate a press of the home button’.